# How to remove everything after specific character in string using Java

Tags: java, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
analitics@gmail.com@5
```

And it represents my `userId`.

I have to send that `userId` as parameter to the function and send it in the way that I remove number 5 after second `@` and append new number.

I started with something like this:

```
userService.getUser(user.userId.substring(0, userAfterMigration.userId.indexOf("@") + 1) + 3
```

What is the best way of removing everything that comes after the second `@` character in string above using Java?

Comment: What is the exact output?

Comment: Hi I updated my question, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a splitting option:

```java
String input = "analitics@gmail.com@5";
String output = String.join("@", input.split("@")[0], input.split("@")[1]) + "@";
System.out.println(output);  // analitics@gmail.com@
```

Assuming your input would only have *two* at symbols, you could use a regex replacement here:

```java
String input = "analitics@gmail.com@5";
String output = input.replaceAll("@[^@]*$", "@");
System.out.println(output);  // analitics@gmail.com@
```

Comment: output from your code that I need for my example would be `analitics@gmail.com@`I just want to return everything after my second @

Comment: @user9347049 That's not what your question says "So how can I remove everything after second @ with Java?" So which is it?

Comment: Everything that comes after secon @ what ever it is....

Comment: @user9347049 Check my updated answer.  I suggest using s splitting option.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture in group 1 what you want to keep, and match what comes after it to be removed.

In the replacement use capture group 1 denoted by `$1`

```
^((?:[^@\s]+@){2}).+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:[^@\s]+@){2}` Repeat 2 times matching 1+ chars other than @, and then match the @
- `)` Close group 1
- `.+` Match 1 or more characters that you want to remove

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gxvFyQ/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UAwAS7)

```
String s = "analitics@gmail.com@5";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^((?:[^@\\s]+@){2}).+", "$1"));
```

Output

```
analitics@gmail.com@
```

---

If the string can also start with `@@1` and you want to keep `@@` then you might also use:

```
^((?:[^@]*@){2}).+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpSn3A/1)

Comment: As output I need `analitics@gmail.com@`

Comment: @user9347049 I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The *simplest* way that would seem to work for you:

```
str = str.replaceAll("@[^.]*$", "");
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/dnhEFxKEqWH9m1).

This matches (and replaces with blank to delete) `@` and any non-dot chars to the end.